# Travis CI - Swift Package Manage - checkout already exists?

Tags: swift, xcode, travis-ci, swift-package-manager

Attempting to setup a sample project within a project that is configured to use Swift Package Manager and getting a strange error.

**Project Structure:**

```
MyProject/
    - Package.swift
    MyProject/
        - etc...
    Samples/
        - MySampleProject/
```

**Swift Package Repository Setup:**

`MySampleProject` is set up to  use a local Swift package that should exist in the travis job:

`file:///Users/travis/build/MyProject/MyProject` <- pointed to branch: `HEAD`

**Travis build command:**

The travis script cd's into Sample/MySampleProject and runs:

`xcodebuild clean build -target MySampleProject -sdk iphonesimulator`

**Error:**

During the run, travis is claiming the checkout of the package already  exists.

From the logs:

```
Resolve Package Graph

Fetching /Users/travis/build/<namespace>/MyProject

Cloning /Users/travis/build/<namespace>/MyProject

xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:

  An unknown error occurred. '/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySampleProject-agdvdspgtwakvignsmkkrkoxijnm/SourcePackages/checkouts/MyProject' exists and is not an empty directory (-4)
```

This works locally. Why would the checkout already be present in derived data for the travis builds? I'm not running any special commands to modify anything regarding SPM.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am currently experiencing the same only on Bitrise instead of travis CI

Comment: Unfortunately not. :( This is not great imo.

Comment: Since we use fastlane I found an issue which when solved should help us. Maybe you can find a hint for your Problem in this thread.
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two things to realize:

1. The error message is very misleading. You will get this error message if there is not actually a commit to pull.
2. A coworker pointed out that Travis is actually using `refs/pull/$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST/merge` for the value of `$TRAVIS_COMMIT`

#### Full solution:

Find the object in the plist that corresponds to `XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference`
You can find this by opening `YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` in a text editor and searching for `XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference`. Grab the ID since you'll need to hardcode it in your build step.

**Note**: You'll need to update this if you remove and re-add the package.

Next use PlistBuddy to update the branch to be the merge ref for the pull request.

```
    echo "Updating project file to point to merge commit at: refs/pull/$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST/merge"
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
        -c "set :objects:F4CEA53E23C29C9E0086EB16:requirement:branch refs/pull/$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST/merge" \
        YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

    # Redirecting to /dev/null because we only care about errors here and the full output drowns Travis
    xcodebuild build -scheme YourScheme \
      -sdk iphonesimulator > /dev/null
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the above did help me.  Here is what I did.

I removed the package dependency in the using project and then deleted the ../Xcode/DerivedData/usingProject directory.  Then, I opened the swift package in Xcode and did a git checkout on the lates version (tagged 1.0.11).  Lastly, in Xcode, I selected the using project -> Swift Packages and added (+) the local URL to the package's folder:

file:///Users/me/repository/mySwiftPackageFolder

The build finally worked on the using project.

Note, simply deleting the derived data or the mentioned checkouts directory doesn't fix the error.  I needed a clean derived data, a good package checkout, and a package folder URL.