# How to trigger Xcode's 'Update to Latest Package Versions' from command line?

Tags: swift, xcode, continuous-integration, swift-package-manager

#### Goal:

I want to programmatically update the versions of Swift Packages consumed by a sample project.

#### Problem:

Xcode > 11 offers a menu option:

> File > Swift Packages > Update to Latest Package Versions

This will update the `Package.resolved` file to point to a specific revision.

This file is located at:

`MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved`

How can I trigger this action from the command line for a CI build?

Comment: Closest thing I found: `xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies` which I guess is like a `pod install` but no (visible?) option for explicit updates...

Comment: @Alladinian have you checked if this actually updates or just resolves to what's in an existing package.resolved file?

Comment: I did check. It fetches & clones the repos for all the dependencies but doesn't seem to even check for updates afterwards (hence the mention of `pod install`)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Wound up abandoning this route since ideally CI tests what **GOING** to be in the repo instead of what **IS** in the repo.

End solution wound up being to point to a dummy branch and then force push the CI-generated merge commit to that branch.

It's a little hacky but gives accurate feedback on how the package will be consumed post-merge.

**Update:**
Was able to find a way better solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61110638/2565025

Comment: This isn't really the answer to the question that was asked. I think @joshbillions answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Question is about Xcode Server not the travis the method in the linked page is not even helping for similar solution for Xcode Server.

Comment: @J.beenie : That one isn't an answer to the question either. Resolving packages and updating them do different things. They have different underlying `swift` commands and different buttons in the Xcode UI. This question specifically asks how to run the update command for an Xcode project from the command line. Not the resolve command.

Answer (score 8):

Try out `xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies`

Comment: This does not do the same thing as "Update to Latest Package Versions" — it just makes sure the local caches match what is currently expected.

Answer (score 8):

`xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies` does not seem to work reliably. It will often stubbornly refuse to update to the latest version, particularly when an SPM dependency is pointed to a branch rather than a version tag. Obviously Xcode is caching this information somewhere, but I could not figure out exactly which file it is. Even nuking the `SourcePackages` folder in the derived data did not do the trick.

The only way I have found to do this reliably is to nuke the entire `DerivedData` subfolder for the Xcode project.

```sh
derived=$(xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep -m 1 BUILD_DIR | grep -oE "\/.*" | sed 's|/Build/Products||')
# The above will return a folder with a name like /Users/you/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-ehdkocavaenextdcrsaszjdmyssx
rm -rf "$derived"
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies
```

It is completely safe to delete the DerivedData subfolder for a project. Xcode will simply regenerate it on demand.

Comment: `derived` folder is the resolved version of cached versions in `~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/` i'm not sure any other way to update that cache folder than `Update to Latest Package Versions`

Comment: `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` will resolve package dependencies before showing settings, so if failed to resolve, `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` displays only error messages.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I set the exact version in package dependency (like in the post above).

Answer (score 1):

If you have your rules set to next minor and the next version is major, clicking update won't work, you will have to change your package settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your main Xcode project, under "Package dependencies" in project navigator:

- select the dependency you want to update
- right click > open in finder (this is under derived data)
- open this location in terminal
- run command: `swift package update`

Note:
You can learn more about SPM CLI here:
https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager