# How to update swift package using command line?

Tags: xcode, github-actions, swift-package-manager

We are integrating Github Actions to our project which uses Swift Package Manager. We want to update those swift packages from the CICD. We have tried using commands like
**xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies** and **xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -project myproject.xcodeproj -scheme my scheme**

But these commands are not working. Can someone please help on how to update the swift packages either from terminal command line or GitHub Actions?

Comment: [hope this works ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755069/how-to-trigger-xcodes-update-to-latest-package-versions-from-command-line) for the question

Comment: [hope this works] It does **not** work ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Without error logs its hard to help, but the command `xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies` should work, just make sure  you ran it on root directory.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, `for CI`, you can `specify the minimum version` number on `Project` -> `Package Dependencies`. Seems working correctly for me. ✌

[image: enjoy]