# Swift Package Manager relying on outdated source

Tags: swift, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I have a SwiftPM issue which is driving me nuts.

Let’s say I have swift package project (no Xcode project involved). And let’s call it SDK from here. The SDK is laying in its own git repository.
So I want to build a Showcase App for that SDK by adding the SDK as a dependency, managing swift packages via Xcode not via a `Package.swift` file. The showcase is deployed to our QA team and they should be able to always test the latest development version of the SDK with that showcase.

So naturally I would configure the package dependency in Xcode by defining the branch develop.
[image: Adding a package dependency via Xcode]

So now, when I change something inside the SDK, push it onto the `develop` branch, and want to have that change available inside the showcase, I simply need to right click on the package inside the showcase and click `Update Package` and this works great.

Here comes the catch: This approach does not work on our Jenkins CI. I don’t know what I’m doing wrong here, but the `xcodebuild` command line tool won’t notice something changed on the `develop` branch of the SDK and would checkout the older revision.

What I tried so far:

- I removed `Package.resolved` from git index and added it to `.gitignore` so after the git clone/checkout there should be no `Package.resolved` file
- I removed `~/Library/Cache/org.swift.swiftpm` and `~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm` prior to the build
- I am deleting any previously created workspace of the Jenkins Build Job prior to each build
- We’re using `Fastlane` and so I am also explicitly setting the cloned source packages path to something inside my workspace to make sure the cloned sources are deleted on workspace clean-up via `cloned_source_packages_path: "SourcePackages"`

The generated `xcodebuild` command by Fastlane looks like this: `$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -scheme ScannerShowcase -project ScannerShowcase.xcodeproj -configuration Release -clonedSourcePackagesDirPath SourcePackage`

The Fastlane gym summary looks like this:
[image: The gym summary]

I'd expect that if I delete all that cached packages and not having any `Package.resolved` file present `xcodebuild` would resolve the swift package to the latest revision available. Instead it seems there still is something cached somewhere and `xcodebuild` is using that cache.

Nothing worked so far. Does anybody have experienced this same issue and is able to provide any suggestions and/or help?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there seems to be now way to achieve the same results with `xcodebuild` command line tool as with Xcode's `Update Package` or `Update to Latest Versions`.

The command line tools rely on data stored inside derived data while updating packages. Thanks to [Gregory Higley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27779/gregory-higley)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67006537/2491315) I was able to solve the issue by deleting the derived data for that specific build job by

- Keeping `Showcase.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved` out of git index,
- adding `Package.resolved` to `.gitignore`to keep it that way,
- and adding the following stage to the declarative pipeline inside the `Jenkins` file:

```
stage('Clean up') {
    steps {
        script { env.DERIVED_DATA_PATH=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep -m 1 BUILD_DIR | grep -oE \"/.*\" | sed 's|/Build/Products||'") }
        echo "Derived data path is: ${env.DERIVED_DATA_PATH}"
        // The above will return a folder with a name like /Users/you/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-ehdkocavaenextdcrsaszjdmyssx
        sh script: "rm -rf ${env.DERIVED_DATA_PATH}", label: "Removing derived project data ..."
    }
}
```

Any other step I mentioned when asking the question wasn't necessary to achieve my goal:

- No need to remove `~/Library/Cache/org.swift.swiftpm` nor `~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm`
- No need to delete any prior created workspace on the build node
- No need to to explicitly specify the SPM cloned source packages path via Fastlane with. `cloned_source_packages_path: "SourcePackages"`

Again big shout out to [Gregory Higley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27779/gregory-higley) for their approach.